# Nginx PHP-FPM flooding the logs from 127.0.0.1 in Docker

Tags: php, laravel, docker, nginx, alibaba-cloud

PHPFPM access log keep flooding the logs from 127.0.0.1 which the server is currently no outside access at all. Im using laravel by the way. This setup is based on dockerfile from [webdevops](https://github.com/webdevops/Dockerfile)

Below is my nginx config for php

[image]

[image]

Im not sure whether it is normal or what. Because if i do php-fpm setup in fresh server without docker i not facing this flooding log issue.

Comment: [Did you by any chance bind docker to 127.0.0.1 with the `-H` switch?](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#bind-docker-to-another-host-port-or-a-unix-socket)

Comment: @Sherif im not sure but im just run command `docker build -t tag_name`